# Why does the update algorithm of HMAC_DRBG use two rounds?

Tags: random-number-generator, hmac

I read this [paper](http://repo.flib.u-fukui.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/10098/2126/1/art.pdf), which said that $\operatorname{update}(K, V, adin)$ should do two rounds as follows:

$\operatorname{update}(K, V , adin)$:

1. $K = H(K, V || 0x00 || adin)$
2. $V = H(K, V )$
3. If $adin = null$, then return $(K, V )$
4. $K = H(K, V || 0x01 || adin)$
5. $V = H(K, V )$
6. Return $(K, V )$

Why is the second round ($K = H(K, V || 0x01 || adin)$) necessary in the case where $adin$ is attacker-controlled? Since the attacker doesn't know the initial value of $K$, shouldn't the new value of $K$ as $H(K, V || 0x00 || adin)$ be unpredictable to the attacker?